# Is there a way to delete only specific product variations by title content?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am seeking a way how to delete product variations by filtering phrases in the variations title.

I use this post filter:

```
            case 'trash_unwanted_products':
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => array('product','product_variation'),
                    'post_status' => array('publish','draft'),
                    'no_found_rows' => true,
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                    'fields' => 'ids',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'order' => 'asc',
                );
                break;
```

And this is my set of post trashing functions:

```
private function trash_unwanted_products($product) {
    if (!$product->exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    $productName = $product->get_name();
    $productName_slug = sanitize_title($productName);
    $productName_dash = sanitize_title_with_dashes($productName);
    $productSKU = $product->get_sku();

    if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {

        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
        $title_slug = current($variation->get_variation_attributes());

        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE slug = '{$title_slug}'", ARRAY_A);
        $variationName = $results[0]['name'];
        $variationName_slug = sanitize_title($variationName);
        $variationName_dash = sanitize_title_with_dashes($variationName);
    }

    if (strpos($productName_slug,'ubrus')!==false && strpos($productName_slug,'vanocni')!==false) {
        $this->trash_product($product);
    }

    if ($product->is_type( 'variable' ) && strpos($variationName_slug,'latka')!==false && strpos($variationName_dash,'cena-za-1-bezny-metr')!==false) {
        $this->wp_delete_post($variation->get_id(), true);
    }
}

private function trash_product($product) {
    wp_delete_post($product->get_id(), true);
}
```

However, I am not sure if the script goes through all variations in each variable product and thus has the ability to delete the targeted product variations.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed my own filter for variations, but I haven´t had the opportunity to test it yet.

```
            case 'trash_unwanted_variations':
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
                    'no_found_rows' => true,
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                    'fields' => 'ids',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'order' => 'asc',
                    's' => get_search_query(),
                    'title' => array(
                        array(
                            'value' => sanitize_title_with_dashes('cena-za-1-bezny-metr'),
                            'compare' => 'IN',
                            )
                        ), 
                );
                break;
```

Could this perhaps solve the question? (if is going to work) :D..